# how is const and #define differentiated in assembly

Tags: assembly, constants

I know that that using the word "Equ", it is possible to define a constant in assembly. Is it equivalent to "const" or "#define" in C? if it is equivalent to "#define", how a "const" is defined in assembly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar/same as a simple define   #define hello 5  but for macro type defines you have to use a macro.

Comment: of course assembly language directives are specific to the assembly language which is specific to the assembler the program you are using, not the target.

Comment: Const is a constant but a storage is reserved for it. I want to know how can we define such thing in assembly (of 8086, I mean)?

Comment: the assembly language is defined first by the assembler then by the target. 8086 doesnt tell us anything until we first know the assembler.

Comment: After the C compiler is done with it, you'd generally see it back with the equivalent of DB or MOV reg,imm.  Just look at the assembly listing you get back from the compiler, they all support generating one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `equ` directive ist most similar to declaring an `enum` in C as an actual symbol is generated. A macro defined with `#define` is just a textual replacement, it's the same thing as if you'd define a macro in your assembler (the syntax depends on what assembler you use).

An object declared `const` is indistinguishable from an unqualified object if its storage duration is automatic. If the storage duration is static, the `const` qualifier is typically reflected in the object being placed in the `.text` or `.rodata` (if available) section as these two can't be written to. For example, a statement like

```
const int taxicab = 1729;
```

might be compiled to

```
         section .rodata
taxicab: dd 1729
```

in nasm syntax.

Comment: Const is a constant but a storage is reserved for it. How can we define such thing in assembly (of 8086, I mean)?

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible for us to define .rodata segment? If not, then isn't there a way for the programmer to define something in assembly which would be equivalent  to "const" in C?

Comment: @Cror2014 Whether you can define a rodata segment or not depends on your toolchain. Some toolchains only support data/text/bss while others are more flexible. For your second question, I believe I have already answered that.